# How to tabulate three variables with tables in R

Tags: r, tabular

I am trying to tabulate `df` dataframe using three variables using `tabular` from the `tables`package. The format of the result is OK but I don't understand why the values are all equal to `1` instead of using the `values` variable (frequency).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tables)

df <- tibble(UT = c(rep(1, 9), rep(2,9)),
             sex = rep(c(rep('MF', 3), rep('M', 3), rep('F', 3)),2),
             age = rep(c('a','b','c'), 6),
             values = c(1:18))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(c(UT, sex, age), as.factor))


tabular(UT ~ (age * sex), data=df)
#>                               
#>     age                       
#>     a        b        c       
#>     sex      sex      sex     
#>  UT F   M MF F   M MF F   M MF
#>  1  1   1 1  1   1 1  1   1 1 
#>  2  1   1 1  1   1 1  1   1 1
Created on 2022-09-22 with reprex v2.0.2
```

Comment: I think the combination frequency is 1 i.e. `ftable(df[1:3])`

Comment: @akrun But, for example, the combination UT=2, sex=F and age=c, has a frequency of 18 (values).

Comment: I get 1 row in the example `nrow(subset(df, UT == 2 & sex == "F" & age == 'c'))#
[1] 1`

Comment: @akrun Yes, because you didn't consider the variable `values` which is the frequency.

Comment: Yes, but the `tabular` also didn't consider that i.e. you may need `xtabs(values ~ ., df)`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps

```
tabular((values)*(sum) ~ (UT *age *sex), data = df)
```

-output

```
     UT                                                      
            1                          2                            
            age                        age                          
            a        b        c        a         b         c        
            sex      sex      sex      sex       sex       sex      
            F   M MF F   M MF F   M MF F   M  MF F   M  MF F   M  MF
 values sum 7   4 1  8   5 2  9   6 3  16  13 10 17  14 11 18  15 12
```

---

Or in `base R` with `xtabs`

```
xtabs(values ~ ., df)
```

Comment: It's a pity that `UT` is not isolated by row.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using `pivottabler` package.

```
library(pivottabler)
qhpvt(df,"UT",  c("age", "sex"), "sum(values)", totals="NONE")
```